# jQuery parse object to a secondary function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse `$(this)` to a function called by another function but without much luck.  Essentially my question is; is it possible and if so, how?

Code is as follows:

> Initial Call

```
$('.playform').on('click', playForm);
```

> Primary Function

```
function playForm(e){
    ...snip...
TweenLite.to($('.video'), 1, {css:{'height':win.h+'px'}, ease:Power4.easeInOut, onComplete:showForm});
    ...snip...
}
```

> Secondary Function

```
function showForm{
   $('.video #youtube').append('<iframe class="show-form" src="'+$('.playform').attr('href')+'"></iframe>');
}
```

As I am going to be using more than one form, I wanted to automate this process but I cant seem to

> Things I have tried so far but to no avail

1. Declared `$(this)` as a variable
2. Tried to give the functions parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" ?

Comment: He probably means "to pass a variable to another function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1

```
$('.playform').on('click', function(){
    var whichVid = $(this);
    playForm(whichVid);
});
```

Step 2

```
function playForm(e){
    TweenLite.to($('.video'), 1, {css:{'height':win.h+'px'}, ease:Power4.easeInOut, onComplete:showForm(e)});

}
```

Step 3

```
function showForm(e){
 $('.video #youtube').append('<iframe class="show-form" src="'+e.attr('href')+'"></iframe>');
}
```

Alternatively you could establish a global variable before step 1 and then set the value on the click event like

```
var window.whichVid = '';

$('.playform').on('click', function(){
    window.whichVid = $(this);
    playForm();
});

function playForm(){
    TweenLite.to($('.video'), 1, {css:{'height':win.h+'px'}, ease:Power4.easeInOut, onComplete:showForm()});

}

function showForm(){
 var thisVid = whichVid.attr('href');
 $('.video #youtube').append('<iframe class="show-form" src="'+ thisVid +'"></iframe>');
}
```

Comment: @TimVermaelen That's what I thought but I ignored my instincts x)

Comment: deleted my comment since you changed it, just mentioning ... :) also .prop('href') is more correct ^^
and another thing, since e is usually used as an `event` it becomes misleading since you are using e for `this`

Comment: thanks heaps. the first option was the one that I got to work. @VIDesignz

Answer (score 0):

you could put it like this (not tested) :

```
(function($){
    var global_this;

    function palyform(e){
        global_this = $(this)
        ...
    }

    function showform(e){
        // do shomething with global_this
        ...
    }

    $('.playform').on('click', playForm);
}(jQuery);
```